# Error in copying data from table A to table B

Tags: mysql

I am facing an error

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '42322-xyz@yahoo.co.in' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

while copying data from one table to another.
is it possible to by-pass rows from table A which are in table B, I am trying to use

```
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA as A join v2_opens as B on A.id!=B.id and A.emailid != B.emailid WHERE  A.date='2015-01-27';
```

but for above query i am getting an error:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Would request you to suggest and help me how to overcome these issue.
My concern is to copy data from TableA to TableB, if there comes any duplicate entry(with primary key) than it must be by-passed.

Comment: To ignore the Key constraints use `INSERT IGNORE ...` then only data that has no duplicate unique-key constraint will be copied.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` ignores the error, not the constraint.

Comment: i am not able to get why INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA as A join v2_opens as B on A.id!=B.id and A.emailid != B.emailid WHERE  A.date='2015-01-27'; not working...

Answer (score 0):

For bypassing rows, I prefer `on duplicate key update`.  This prevents exactly that error.

When doing an insert, you should generally include the columns you want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO tableB(col1, . . .)
    SELECT col1, . . .
    FROM tableA as A join
         v2_opens as B on A.id <> B.id and A.emailid <> B.emailid
    WHERE  A.date='2015-01-27'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = values(col1);
```

However, I would be surprised if this query were really want you wanted to do.  This may be sufficient:

```
INSERT INTO tableB(col1, . . .)
    SELECT col1, . . .
    FROM tableA a
    WHERE  A.date = '2015-01-27'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = values(col1);
```

Or perhaps this:

```
INSERT INTO tableB(col1, . . .)
    SELECT col1, . . .
    FROM tableA as A LEFT JOIN
         v2_opens as B
         ON A.id = B.id and A.emailid = B.emailid
    WHERE A.date = '2015-01-27' AND B.id IS NULL;
```